# MSBuild: why does it not copy my files

Tags: msbuild

In VS2010 project file I have this, yet it does not copy the files at all. Why?

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="xcopy.exe /Y /S $(ProjectDir)Templates\*.tt  $(dev_folder)MyWebsites\DotNetNuke%20Community%20Edition\DesktopModules\SharpMod\Templates\"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: What is the output of the AfterBuild target? Any error messages?

Comment: @Eric: Error 1 The command "xcopy.exe /Y /S C:\software\dynomod\DnnModules\dnnSphere.DNNModules.SharpMod\Templates\*.tt  c:\softwareMyWebsites\DotNetNuke Community Edition\DesktopModules\SharpMod\Templates\" exited with code 4. C:\software\dynomod\DnnModules\dnnSphere.DNNModules.SharpMod\dnnSphere.DNNModules.SharpMod.csproj 243 5 dnnSphere.DNNModules.SharpMod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be because you've got spaces in your paths. Try to use double quotes:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="xcopy.exe /Y /S &quot;$(ProjectDir)Templates\*.tt&quot;  &quot;$(dev_folder)MyWebsites\DotNetNuke%20Community%20Edition\DesktopModules\SharpMod\Templates\&quot;"/>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

XCopy [code 4](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true) is a permissions or file space issue

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a backslash after `$(dev_folder)` in your destination. Looking at your comment response to Eric, it's resulting in `c:\softwareMyWebsites\DotNetNuke Community Edition\DesktopModules\SharpMod\Templates\` - notice the missing path delimiter between `software` and `MyWebsites`.